# Xamarin iOS Shell FlyoutMenu not rendering correctly

Tags: ios, shell, xamarin

I am using `Shell` in my App to handle navigation between views and its `FlyoutMenu` works perfectly on Android as can be seen here:

[Screenshot of FlyoutMenu on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnfpG.png)

However, when I open the Flyout on iOS it looks completely different (and wrong):

[Screenshot of FlyoutMenu on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVM2K.png)

This is the code I have in my AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CMApp.AppShell"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Title="Cargomando"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:CMApp"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:CMApp.Resources"             
             FlyoutBackgroundColor="LightGray">
    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <Image Source="cargomando.png"/>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <FlyoutItem Title="{x:Static resources:Tour.TitleString}">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent>
                <pages:TourList/>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="{x:Static resources:Settings.TitleString}">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent>
                <pages:Settings/>
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <MenuItem Text="{x:Static resources:Footer.PrivacyProtection}" Command="{Binding PrivacyProtectionCommand}"/>
    <MenuItem Text="{x:Static resources:Footer.Imprint}" Command="{Binding ImprintCommand}"/>
    <MenuItem Text="DEBUG: Tracking stoppen" Command="{Binding StopTrackingCommand}"/>
</Shell>
```

What am I doing wrong that it works fine on Android but not on iOS? Thanks!

Comment: I used similar code and it works fine on my side . So you could share your sample to github so that I can test it directly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During creation of a sample application for Lucas Zhang I noticed that the sample application works fine. After comparing my App and the sample after some digging I noticed that the problem is caused by defining a global style for `Grid` in my `ResourceDictionary` of my `App.xaml`. Xamarin apparently uses a `Grid` for the elements in the `FlyoutMenu` to which my style with a pretty large `HeightRequest` gets applied but this seemingly only happens on iOS.